# when to use destructor in php?

Tags: php

what is the main purpose of a destructor?

could you give any examples of what i might want to run when a object is deleted?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It gives the object an opportunity to prepare to be killed. This could mean manual cleanup, state persistence, etc.

For example, a Model may want to save all of its current properties back into the database.

Or, a Database object itself might want to close the socket it is using to communicate to a database server.

Comment: - It is also use for cleaning up :D

Comment: Also, something to note, __destruct not only gets called with an object is deleted, but also when an object falls out of scope, as well as when the script ends

Answer (score 7):

So, you probably know what a constructor does. If a constructor sets up, a destructor cleans up. Here's an example from the PHP site:

```
<?php
class my_class {
  public $error_reporting = false;

  function __construct($error_reporting = false) {
    $this->error_reporting = $error_reporting;
  }

  function __destruct() {
    if($this->error_reporting === true) $this->show_report();
    unset($this->error_reporting);
  }
?>
```

[Here's the link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to the PHP documentation on the subject.

Comment: Why it even needs to remove anything. If object is being destructed, the references will also be destructed, and when there is no more reference then objects it depends on will also not have reference so those dependencies' destructors will be called.

Answer (score 3):

Say I have a `Result` class that is a wrapper (implementing [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), among other niceties) for the [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. When I destroy one of my `Result` objects, I want to be sure to call the `free()` method on the `mysqli_result` object to reclaim the memory it was using. So I do that in the destructor of my `Result` class.

Answer (score 1):

Reference for book

Destructor often use for close DB connections and `fclose ()` for `fopen()` connection in class